# Erro ao instalar Heroku Toolbelt no Windows

Tags: windows, heroku

Galera alguem pode me ajudar?

Baixei o Heroku Toolbelt no site da Heroku.com mas esta dando esse erro.
Ele fala "MySQL" ...

Será que é alguma configuração nas variaveis de ambiente?

[image: Erro Heroku]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removi completamente o MySQL da maquina e funcionou.